# findViewHolderForAdapterPosition() returns null

Tags: java, android

I know this question has been asked with the exact same title but a decent solution was not provided, hence my "duplicate".

when adding a new Item to the recyclerView, I want to set the focus to the latest item (it's a list of EditText's). However, because of recalculating the view, calling "findViewHolderForAdapterPosition" returns null. It could be solved by waiting half a second before calling the function as shown here

```
addOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                optionsAdapter.addOption();
                optionsRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int last = optionsAdapter.getItemCount()-1;
                        OptionsAdapter.OptionViewHolder o = (OptionsAdapter.OptionViewHolder) optionsRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(last);
                        o.editText.setSelected(true);
                    }
                },500);
            }
        });

//OptionsAdapter class
public void addOption()
{
    values.add("");
    notifyItemInserted(values.size()-1);
}
```

However, it is not the neatest method nor does it always work. Is there perhaps a better way to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

Another idea:

```
addOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            optionsAdapter.addOption();
            int last = optionsAdapter.getItemCount()-1;
            optionsRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastVisible == last) {
                    optionsRecyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                    OptionsAdapter.OptionViewHolder o = (OptionsAdapter.OptionViewHolder) optionsRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(last);
                    o.editText.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
            optionsRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(last);
        }
    });
```

Try this:

```
addOptionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            optionsAdapter.addOption();
            int last = optionsAdapter.getItemCount()-1;
            optionsRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(last);
            OptionsAdapter.OptionViewHolder o = (OptionsAdapter.OptionViewHolder) optionsRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(last);
            o.editText.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This was what I originally had but does not work since "o" will always be null

Comment: even with the scrollToPosition?

Comment: I added another answer